# What is the mysqli equivalent for this mysql_result statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is the code I was using with mysql and now I am trying to convert all of my functions over to mysqli. How would I format this so that it returns the values I need?

```
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Well, for a start, your _old_ code is rubbish :-) You could have just used `return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1)` without the ternary.

Comment: lol. well my old code came from phpacademy videos so theres not much I can do about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqli has a main function "query" 
If it's CRUD SQL it will return 1 or 0 (success or not) if it's select SQL it will return the result

```
$sqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,
                            DB_USERNAME,
                            DB_PASSWORD,
                            DB_NAME);
$result = $sqli->query("INSERT INTO...");
return ($result == 1) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `return  ($mysqli->query($query) == 1)` but that is just me, i believe you can then checke returned value for a boolean

Comment: well what would I do if I wanted to do this procedurally?

Comment: mysqli is not a procedural language, so I believe you have to use OOP features here

Comment: well then why does the php manual offer OOP and procedural options for using mysqli functions? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php